# Vaadin Combobox Data binding

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a problem with include data from a `datasource` in a `combobox`. 
My first `Combobox` is filled that way -

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;


    public Person (final String firstName, final String lastName) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }
}
```

Now I create a `BeanContainer` and fill it -

```
  Combobox Name = new Combobox("Person");

  final BeanItemContainer<Person> personContainer = new BeanItemContainer<Person>(Person.class);

  this.personContainer.setBeanIdProperty("firstName");

  BeamItem person1 = personContainer.addBean(new Person("Tom", "Bauer"));
  BeanItem person2 = personContainer.addBean(new Person("Laura", "Simpsons"));
  BeanItem person3 = personContainer.addBean(new Person("John", "Doe"));

  this.Name.setContainerDataSource(personContainer);
  this.Name.setRequired(true);
  this.Name.setImmediate(true);
  this.Name.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
```

So the result is a filled `Combobox`. So far so good. But now I want to create a second Combobox which is dependet from the Person `Combobox`. So lets call the second Combobox phonenumbers. When I select an item in the first Combobox, i want that the items in the phone combobox are going to change their value based on the name the user have selected. The Phonenumbers I will get from the backend similiar to the Names from the first Combobox.

Comment: have you looked at the docs? https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.selection.html#components.selection.valuechange . make combobox `immediate`, listen for changes and then fill the next box depending of the value of your `Name` field. And by convention, your field should be named `name` (lowercase)

Comment: Hey , thanks for you answer. I tried to use a Properties.ValueChangelistener. But the problem is that i have a lot of such dependencies and Comboboxes which are build dependet from each other. So i dont want to use so much ChangeListener. Do you have another solution?

Comment: define it in a generic way and write functions around it.  e.g. write a CustomField or some glue code, that handels that for you.  if there are heavy dependencies, there is an example to use RX https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/reactive-functional-ui-development-with-vaadin and of course you check the addons, if there is something that fits your needs.